# Formula to display items that have more than one value selected in a custom multi select field

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

I need help with creating a search to display only items that have more than one value selected in a custom multi select field. Is that a possibility via a formula?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Below Formula

LENGTH({custitem25}) - LENGTH(REPLACE({custitem25},',', ''))

[image]

**Note:** If your Multiselect field value does't contains comma.

If comma not there in your multiselect Field then it is working fine

Comment: Is it possible to use case when statement on this?  I'm running a transaction search and need to add couple columns to display sales or quantities only when the items custom field has more than one value selected, and otherwise null 0 value.

Answer (score 0):

The folllowing is just a case of using that formula as the condition to check and use the usual `WHEN`/`THEN`/`ELSE` as usual around it.

```
CASE WHEN LENGTH({user.custentity_zel_ae_sales_team.id}) - LENGTH(REPLACE({user.custentity_zel_ae_sales_team.id},',', '')) > 1 THEN 'MORE THEN ONE' ELSE 'ONLY ONE' END
```